# Identify Heroku environment on runtime in Java

Tags: java, heroku

I have a Java SDK which may either run on Heroku, Android, Google App Engine etc. I need to identify when the runtime environment is Heroku. How can  I do that?

Comment: You will likely be able to find the answer in a system property (`System.getProperty("...")`). If you have access to all those environments, you can write a small test program that prints all the system properties, and then see which one might best be used to detect Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

`System.getenv("DYNO")` on Heroku will return the dyno name (like "web.1"). This could be used.

Comment: Does Heroku Dyno always starts with web. ?

Comment: No, it will start with the name of the process type defined in your `Procfile`